# ReSharper InspectCode.exe not taking Custom Layers into account

Tags: c#, resharper

I have quite a lot of C# projects, which can be roughly divided into self-sufficient systems and NuGet packages. I would like to use ReSharper for code quality checks on both types. Most rules are the same, but some, mostly in regard of the visibility, are different.
My approach was to create settings in a centralized repository. The RootSettings configuration has all the settings I would like to have everywhere and a Settings_NuGet configuration overwrites the desired settings.

A NuGet solution would therefore look like this:

[image]

This works great, but I would also like to use the Azure DevOps CI to verify the code quality. To do so, I'm using the task from Alan Wales https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alanwales.resharper-code-analysis, which uses the InspectCode.Exe

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work at all: As I can't use the solution ReSharper settings due to different paths, my approach would be a call like that (with different paths, this call is just locally for testing=:

```
inspectcode.x86.exe "C:\MyGit\Personal\MLH\MLH.LanguageExtensions\MLH.LanguageExtensions.sln" -o="tra.txt" --profile="C:\MyGit\Personal\MLH\MLH.LanguageExtensions\MLH.LanguageExtensions.sln.DotSettings"
```

As MLH.LanguageExtensions.sln.DotSettings is just a proxy to the RootSettings, it seems like the InspectCode is ignoring this. I've verified this, by, instead of targeting the RootSettings, copying all the settings directly into MLH.LanguageExtensions.sln.DotSettings. This approach would work, but it defies my idea of having only one source of truth and all other settings targeting or extending it.

Is this an actual bug of ReSharper? I didn't find anything nor special mentions in the docs.

Edit: A bit more of explanation about the use case: I see two workflows:

- A developer develops locally, using all the goodness of ReSharper. In
  this case, the default settings convention
  MLH.LanguageExtensions.sln" with a absolute path to the root settings
  works well, as we can define the folder structure for developer
  machines.
- In the second workflow, the Azure
  DevOps build pipeline should inspect the code. In this case, I can't
  use the absolute nor the relative path of
  "MLH.LanguageExtensions.sln", as the directories are totally
  different. Therefore, I would like to pass a replacement for the
  "MLH.LanguageExtensions.sln" via the parameter, which doesn't seem to
  work

Why am I even doing this whole tinkering? We have a lot of different repositories, for example for NuGet packages. It would therefore be great to have exactly one ReSharper settings source of truth and local developers as well as the CI targeting the same file without having to copy it around.

Comment: Did you to reach the JB support?

Comment: Consider exporting your settings to .editorconfig

Comment: “can't use the solution ReSharper settings due to different paths” — generally this should not be a problem with CI/InspectCode, what exactly is the problem in this case? The "proxy" settings file references its targets by both absolute and relative paths, and both are probed whichever works. So the referenced files are supposed to load — if their relative location on the CI machine is the same.

Comment: @hypersw I could set up the Azure DevOps CI to pull the two repositories to the same relative path as on the developer machine, but this seems quite a bit of magic. For me, it seems like passing the path to the command is more comprehensible. I've done some more testing and it seems to work fine from the developer machine, just not from the Azure DevOps CI. That said, I see that the the InspectCode takes the passed settings, but just doesn't seem apply them.
I've asked the ReSharper support to have a look, as I don't know how to dig deeper.

Comment: Have you sent the details there, like, settings files? I see now that relative paths are different on the CI because of two separate repos (and absolute paths are even more different:), but what is passing the path to inspectcode going to do? In your example in the question you're passing solution settings which sit next to solution file itself, this would have been loaded anyway. Inside that file are paths to two real settings files, which do not hit the files on the CI due to different paths. Are you also editing the file contents to adjust the paths?

Comment: @hypersw Yes, it's quite to explain. I have two workflows in mind: A developer uses ReSharper locally, in this case the default SolutionName.sln.DotSettings with the absolute paths are used --> Everything fine.
The second workflow is the inspection of the code on the Azure DevOps pipeline. In this case, the absolute nor relative path work, as they are totally different from the local environment. Therefore, I need to pass the settings to use to InspectCode.exe. BUT I can say, that the RootSettings and the ProxySettings I would like to use, are in the same path. I'll add some more explanation.